# Stack overflow error in IE 7 and 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, prototypejs, stack-overflow

I have a rails application in which i am using scriptaculous,prototip,controlMModal(livepipe.net).
I am getting an error in IE 7 and 8 as web page error (alert box)
The error is

> "Stack overflow at line 1715"

Versions used:
scriptaculous v 1.8.3
prototip 2.2.0.2
prototype 1.6.1
controlmodal 2.2.3 (livepipe.net)

Comment: +1 for generating a stack overflow, and coming here to resolve it.

Comment: Please consider adding "javascript", "internet-explorer" and "stack-overflow" tags and removing misspell "prototip" tag to support correct indexing and searching in future.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a prototype error. you have to change some lines of code in your prototype.js as explain [here](https://prototype.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8886/tickets/824-stack-overflow-error)

Answer (score 0):

On topic, IE has a lower call stack threshold than other browsers. For example, on Firefox, you can call 3000 functions deep before a stack overflow.

Check to see if your code is doing too much, and if you can split up into mini-tasks.